# QList::iterator only returns (error)0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I am using  a QList and I want to iterator though it, but the iterator that i get from it keeps failing, even if I use the auto keyword or not.

```
for( auto iter = myModel->getList().begin(); iter != myModel->getList().end(); ++iter )
{
    if( (*iter)->getList().empty() )
    {
        if( (*iter)->getData()->getCode() == baseData->getCode() )
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Or is there a different way that I am to use the QList::iterator?

EIDT:
I have noticed another odd thing about this. I do see that the iterator is showing (error)0, and this is odd because it actually contains the data I need.

But if I edit my code to look like this:

```
QList<T*> tempList = myModel->getList();    
for( auto iter = tempList .begin(); iter != tempList .end(); ++iter )
        {
            if( (*iter)->getList().empty() )
            {
                if( (*iter)->getData()->getCode() == baseData->getCode() )
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

then everything works fine. I guess it is a solution, but does anyone know why it needs to be done like this? Or am I just not seeing something very important?

Comment: What exactly returns 0? What are the types of those variables, are you sure that myModel->getList() returns what you want?

Comment: iter is a QList<T*>::iterator and myModel->getList() returns a QList<T*> so that when I use the begin(), it should give me the iterator to myModel->getList(). And either way, because I am using the auto keyword, as long as the getList() returns a QList, iter should be an iterator to some list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues with the code.

a) `myModel->getList()` returns a copy of your QList declared something like this:

```
QList<T*> YourModel::getList()
```

you actually should get an access violation. But I don't know if that's what happening.

b) If you only rely on what Visual Studio is saying about iter, forget it, its wrong. It just can't handle the iterator. Allthough the iterator says its (error)0 as an int it will still give you the correct data if dereferenced.

If none of the above is the case please specify what actually goes wrong, is the for loop beeing skipped all together? If so, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Best regards
D

EDIT
The reason why it works fine with the temporary List object is following:
The moment you create an iterator with the `begin()` method of the list, the list detaches its private data (implicit sharing), meaning it creates a deep copy of itself because you could change the data with that iterator. Without the temporary object `myModel->getList()` creates a temporary object which immediately after the iterator has been created is beeing destroyed. From that moment on the iterator points to nowhere. You might try using the `const iterator`, this one should work without detaching the private data hence without the problem.
Another approach would be to make your model return the list as a const reference or a pointer.
Another way would be to discard iterators and use the `at()` method of the list directly. Makes code more readable in my opinion.

Comment: I've noticed that there is that (error)0 thing, and that it does contain the proper data. But I have noticed another odd thing about this as well. I'll edit and add to my question to show you

Comment: is the copying issue because of the QList?

Comment: Yes. What `myModel->getList()` returns seems to be an unnamed temporary copy of the actual list.

Answer (score 1):

What type does myModel->getList return?

Unless you have a list of lists this line looks suspect:

```
if( (*iter)->getList().empty() )
```

Anyways, the calls themselves overall look good. The only real explanation is either dependent on your types, or the data (or lack thereof) There is no clear and evident problem in the code you posted.

Comment: I am going to be doing some recursion, so that line is to determine if i need to go deeper, but i don't even make it that far, the iter is 0 when created in the for loop

Comment: I don't mean to be condescending when I ask this, but what is the result of myModel->getList().count()?

Comment: And so at what point is iter 0? iter is of type QList::iterator, and not of int type, how are you turning it into an int, and comparing it. What symptoms are you getting an iter == 0 isn't even clearly bad.

Comment: the line "auto iter = myModel->getList().begin()" alone gives me a iterator pointing to 0. It is very weird, and i cannot iterator through my list

Comment: Is the list a a QList<int>? at that point is iter also == myModel->getList().end() ??